# VLOOKUP to condense data into one cell

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm trying to create a macro that takes a user's input and shortens it into an abbreviated code. Say a user has inputted the data into the table:
[image]

The macro would run and output the abbreviated code based on this table (in this case, outputting "BLK190_G16_WFUR12"):

[image]

```
Sub Abbreviated_Code()

'Counts number of partitions
Dim PartitionCount As Integer
PartitionCount = Application.CountIf("B16:B25", "*")

' VLOOKUP loop for as many times there are partition layers
    Let x = 0
    Let materialnum = 16 'First material listed at B16
    Do While x < PartitionCount
    abbrev = Application.VLookup(Range("B" & materialnum), info.Range("C2:D20"), 1, False)
    newCode = abbrev & Range("C" & materialnum)

    x = x + 1
    materialnum = materialnum + 1

    Range("E16") = Range("E16") & newCode & "_" 'Output string of text into cell E16
    Loop

End Sub
```

If anyone could please help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do While x < PartitionCount.... where do use x in your code?

Comment: What goes wrong and where?

Comment: @mooseman I let x = 0 in the beginning of the loop.

Comment: `Application.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("B16:B25"), "*")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I get a 'Type Mismatch' error and it seems to be when I set PartitionCount = Application.CountIf("B16:B25", "*")

Comment: You also need to put some error control.  If the vlookup does not find a match

Comment: @ScottCraner I just made the change and the Type Mismatch error went away! I ran it again and now there seems to be an object error during the VLOOKUP line.

Comment: Vlookup expects the value being looked up to be in the left-most column of the lookup table.

Comment: I've made the user input table to be a dropdown menu which references the same table that the vlookup function references, so someone would not be able to enter a value that was not already there.

Comment: Just an FYI the following Array formula will work if you have Office365: `=TEXTJOIN("_",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(Info!C2:C20,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B16:B25,Info!D2:D20,0)),MATCH(B16:B25,Info!D2:D20,0)*{1,1}))))) & C16:C25,""))`.  Confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter to array enter the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying your code a bit it now works, its a bit messy but error handling is also present in this code. Your data needs to be in `C2` & `B16`.

```
Sub Abbreviated_Code()

'Counts number of partitions
Dim PartitionCount As Integer
PartitionCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B16:B25"), "*")

Range("E16") = ""
' VLOOKUP loop for as many times there are partition layers
    Let x = 0
    Let materialnum = 16 'First material listed at B16
    Do While x < PartitionCount

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("B" & materialnum).Value, Range("D2:D10"), 0)) Then
        abbrev = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C2:C10"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("B" & materialnum).Value, Range("D2:D10"), 0))
    Else:
        GoTo skip:
    End If

    newCode = abbrev & Range("C" & materialnum)

    If Range("E16") = "" Then
        Range("E16") = newCode
    Else:
        Range("E16") = Range("E16") & "_" & newCode 'Output string of text into cell E16
    End If
skip:
    x = x + 1
    materialnum = materialnum + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I've made the changes but now I'm getting an "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Edit: I added the worksheet name of where the vlookup function was referencing, and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: @Jessica See Tim's comment above.  You will need to reorganize the table to put the result to the right of the lookup value or use something else other than VLOOKUP.

Comment: Ok I fixed the errors though the code is a bit messy, it works now with data as it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InputToAbbreviation()
    Dim References As Range, Materials As Range
    Dim reference, material As Range, code As String

    Set References = Range("C2:D20")
    Set Materials = Range("B16:B" & Range("B16").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each material In Materials
        code = code & Application.VLookup(material, References, 2, False) & material.Offset(0, 1) & "_"
    Next

    Debug.Print Left$(code, Len(code) - 1) //Remove trailing '_'
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Re-order your code table to description is in the first column, code the second
- Assumes code descriptions in range C2:D20
- Assumes user inputs material and thickness in row 16 (as your code suggests)